# Python discord.py read full message

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, discord, discord.py

I am using [discord.py](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) to make a [discord](https://discordapp.com/) bot. I would like to generate a random number between 2 numbers mentioned by the user. So if the user types `%rand 1 9`, I would like the bot to return with a random integer between 1 and 9, so say 4. 
Here is my code so far:

```
async def on_message(message):
    x = str(1)
    y = str(2)
    if message.content.startswith('%rand ' + x + y):
        NumberX = int(x)
        NumberY = int(y)
        msg = "Random Number Is: " + str(random.randint(NumberX,NumberY))
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
```

However, it doesn't work. I don't quite understand where I am going wrong. I couldn't find another solution anywhere else. 
I assume I need to force the bot to read the full message or something similar. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are telling it `if message.content.startswith('%rand 12'):` Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from the fact that your if statement is never actually triggered. You are checking whether it starts with "%rand 12" which is not what you are looking for. Here's how your code should look:

```
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('%rand '):
        vals = message.content.split(" ")
        NumberX = int(vals[1])
        NumberY = int(vals[2])
        msg = "Random Number Is: " + str(random.randint(NumberX,NumberY))
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
```

Also, don't forget to `import random` in order to use that function.

Comment: I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: Wait Don't worry, it's just a case of using `message.conent.split` instead of `message.split` Just, edit that in your answer...